# yahoo oauth authentication email scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, symfony-2.3, yahoo-api, hwioauthbundle

I want to implement integration between yahoo and my application (via HWIOAuthBundle) every thing goes well, but in yahoo response i found no email address!! and for my user registration i do need email address.

could anyone help me and say which scope gives you the user email address?
i read https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/extended-profile-resource.html and found no answer.

i can choose between these:

- Contacts
- Fantasy Sports
- Yahoo Gemini Advertising
- Messenger
- Profiles (Social Directory)
- Relationships (Social Directory)

Thanks.

============================

**sample response:**

{ ["paths":protected]=> 
array(7) { ["identifier"]=> string(12) "profile.guid" ["nickname"]=> string(16) "profile.nickname" ["firstname"]=> NULL ["lastname"]=> NULL ["realname"]=> string(17) "profile.givenName" ["email"]=> NULL ["profilepicture"]=> NULL }

["response":protected]=> 
array(1) { ["profile"]=> array(22) { ["guid"]=> string(26) "..." ["ageCategory"]=> string(1) "A" ["created"]=> string(20) "2016-06-06T13:33:40Z" ["image"]=> array(4) { ["height"]=> int(192) ["imageUrl"]=> string(56) "https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/social/profile/profile_b192.png" ["size"]=> string(7) "192x192" ["width"]=> int(192) } 
["intl"]=> string(2) "us" ["jurisdiction"]=> string(2) "us" ["lang"]=> string(5) "en-US" ["memberSince"]=> string(20) "2016-06-06T09:41:48Z" ["migrationSource"]=> int(1) ["nickname"]=> string(6) "Raasco" ["notStored"]=> bool(true) ["nux"]=> string(1) "3" ["profileMode"]=> string(6) "PUBLIC" ["profileStatus"]=> string(6) "ACTIVE" ["profileUrl"]=> string(51) "http://profile.yahoo.com/..." ["updated"]=> string(20) "2016-06-06T13:33:40Z" ["isConnected"]=> bool(false) ["profileHidden"]=> bool(false) ["bdRestricted"]=> bool(true) ["profilePermission"]=> string(7) "PRIVATE" ["uri"]=> string(71) "https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/.../profile" ["cache"]=> bool(true) } }

Comment: Can you provide a JSON or XML sample request / response ?
With that others may help you...

Comment: @AndreDurao i've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is `Contacts` and `Profiles(soacil directory)` API permission required to fetch user email address.

take attention that yahoo will give you all user's emails, with lables. then you can fetch the `primary` one.